# Make Android App Un-Installable without Root ?

Tags: android, root, uninstallation

Is there any way to make Android app Un-installable prgramatically without root my phone?

Comment: Fortunately no, for obvious security reasons. Malware authors would *love* to make it impossible for users to remove the malware.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to create an android app that cannot be un-installed.

Only some system apps that cannot be un-installed. Even they can be un-installed once your phone is rooted.
It creates security risk. A malware could become impossible to remove if once it installed. So no operating system will allow any developer to create this kind of application.

But you can hide the uninstall option. 
You need to gain Device administrator access to your application.

Check this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing) for further information.

Note: App can uninstalled via safe mode.

Comment: I already walk through with above Device administrator access example but it only hide the uninstall option from apps manager in settings menu but if user drag n drop for direct uninstall from apps menu, user will shown a button to disable Device administrator access first, after that he still able to uninstall it..

Is there any other way to prevent user from uninstall or hide install option from drag n drop like system apps (which doesn't show uninstall option)

Comment: Then your app should come up in android os bundle. So that it cant be removed by users without root.

Comment: is that possible to install my android app in os bundle programatically  without root my phone..